# SQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I made one table Login using oracle. Firstly I have taken fields- id,username,password and connected database in java program for signup. I was trying to execute insert query before it was running fine than I altered table Login and dropped column id. Then again I tried to run insert query from java program but now I am getting below error. I am not getting what happened after alteration. I think changes should reflect everywhere but I am stuck with this exception.

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-04098: trigger 'SURABHI.BI_LOGIN' is invalid and failed re-validation

JAVA CODE:

```
public void insertLogin(String user,String pass) {

    String query = "insert into Login(username,password)" + " values(?,?)";
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, user);
        ps.setString(2, pass);
        ps.execute();
        System.out.println("inserted");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should attach table schema and trigger body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your table has a before insert trigger and it is invalid, probably because you dropped column id and it is used by the trigger.

Check your trigger and compile it successfully.

Comment: trigger "BI_LOGIN"   
  before insert on "LOGIN"               
  for each row  
begin   
  if :NEW."ID" is null then 
    select "LOGIN_SEQ".nextval into :NEW."ID" from dual; 
  end if; 
end;

Comment: What should I do now?

Comment: Done. I deleted the trigger. Now code executed properly.Thanks for the hint which I was not getting from the Exception.

Comment: The trigger was used to generate auto numbers in the ID Field. If you don't need the Field anymore, drop the trigger like you did. You can also drop the no longer used sequence LOGIN_SEQ.

Comment: @Surabhi If this answers your question, do not forget to mark it as accepted so that it can be clearly seen that the issue has been resolved.